# DropWizard Graphite Metrics Reporter in config.yml is unable to be parsed

Tags: dropwizard, graphite, codahale-metrics

I tried to configure my dropwizard graphite metrics reporter in my config.yml file:

```
metrics:
  reporters:
     - type: graphite
       host: my.graphite.host.com
       port: 2003
       prefix: my.prefix
```

I have both dropwizard-metrics and metrics-graphite as dependencies in my pom.xml. I have nothing in my Application class or Configuration class regarding the reporter. I was under the impression that DropWizard takes care of all initialization and starting of the MetricRegistry and reporter. Yet, when I run my application, I receive the following error:

```
config.yml has an error:

  * Failed to parse configuration at: metrics.reporters; 
Could not resolve type id 'graphite' into a subtype of [simple type, 
class io.dropwizard.metrics.ReporterFactory]: 
known type ids = [ReporterFactory, console, csv, log] 
at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] 
(through reference chain: com.example.MyConfiguration["metrics"]-  
>io.dropwizard.metrics.MetricsFactory["reporters"])
```

Why is 'graphite' not being picked up as an acceptable type? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you have the answer - but I had the same problem so wanted to detail it.  You need three libraries which wasn't clear in the docs.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        <version>${metrics.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-metrics-graphite</artifactId>
        <version>${dw.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-graphite</artifactId>
        <version>${metrics.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Gradle and the [Shadow plugin](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) to build a fat jar. The reason was that by default service descriptor files that advertise [Java SPIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) for dynamic loading were not being properly merged and included into the final jar. This is why the Graphite reporting plugin did not register the service it was implementing.

From [the Gradle docs](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#controlling_jar_content_merging), forcing the merge is possible with:

```
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

Once I added this to my `build.gradle` the config could be parsed because `graphite` had been properly registered as a sub-type.